# How do you import a module that imports another module in a subfolder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my folder structure:

```
root
  module_a
    hello.py
    submodule_a
      hi.py
  module_b
    howdy.py
```

`hello.py` calls a method in `hi.py`. `howdy.py` calls a method in `hello.py`

This is the content of each file:

`hi.py`

```
def myhi(hi):
    print("myhi " + hi)
```

`hello.py`

```
from submodule_a.hi import myhi

def myhello(hello):
    myhi("myhello " + hello)
```

`howdy.py`

```
from module_a.hello import myhello

def myhowdy(howdy):
    myhello("myhowdy " + howdy)
```

So the first issue is that `howdy.py` cannot find `module_a`, so I did `sys.path.append(".")` inside `howdy.py`.

But now the new problem is that, from `howdy.py`, it cannot find `submodule_a` from `hello.py`.

How do you solve this issue? Is it possible to solve it without editing `hello.py` at all?

I've tried messing with `__init__.py` but I couldn't find anything that could solve the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a `__init__.py` file in `module_a` and `module_b` and `submodule_a` then import the functions you want to use in another directory like these:

module_a/__init__.py

```py
from hello import myhello
from submodule_a import myhi
```

module_a/submodule_a/__init__.py

```py
from hi import myhi
```

module_b/__init__.py

```py
from howdy import myhowdy
```